# Objective-C - How to conform to multiple protocols?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm newish to app developing but have never come across this error before and I am wondering if anyone could help.

In my ViewController.h I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UILabel *Title;
}
```

I have tried to put `<ADBannerViewDelegate>` next to the `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` with just spaces and every other type of character but I can't get it to work. Every time I insert the AD banner it appears with an error of "Protocol has no object type specified; defaults to qualifed 'id'" and "Expected identifier or '('. Heres a picture:

[image: Xcode Error Picture]

So my question is, does anyone know how to put `@interface ViewContorller : UIViewController <UIGetureRecognizerDelegate> //and then <ADBannerViewDelegate>`? If you do your help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protocols should be listed as comma-separated, like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *Title;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Would never think of that.

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves your problem.@JackMoseley